# Perform custom command inside a description environment

Tags: macros, tex-core, description

I have the following code to append new text to a string. But the command doesn't works inside a description enviroment:

```
%preamble
\makeatletter
\global\newcommand{\reqfI}{}
\global\newcommand{\appendFI}[1]{
    \let\OldreqfI\reqfI
    \renewcommand{\reqfI}{\OldreqfI , #1}
}
\makeatother
```

In normal text this works fine:

```
\appendFI{RS001}
\reqfI{}
```

But, this one has no effect:

```
\begin{description}

    \item[RS001:] \appendFI{RS001}
    Must describe the alarms...

\end{description}
\reqfI{}
```

I want to use next to \item, to identify what itens have been picked.

Best Regards,

FULL MINIMAL EXAMPLE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\reqfI}{}
\newcommand{\appendFI}[1]{
    \let\OldreqfI\reqfI
    \renewcommand{\reqfI}{\OldreqfI , #1}
}

\begin{document}
    \appendFI{RS---}
    \reqfI{}
    \begin{description}
        \item[RS001] \appendFI{RS001}
        Must show the alarms description...
    \end{description}
\reqfI{}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: Result of minimal example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\global\newcommand` is wrong. Please, add a full (minimal) example starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in macro `\g@addto@macro` does this (without expansion).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reqfI}{}
\newcommand{\appendFI}[1]{\g@addto@macro\reqfI{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\appendFI{RS001}
\reqfI{}

But, this one has no effect:

\begin{description}

    \item[RS001:] \appendFI{RS001}
    Must describe the alarms...

\end{description}
\reqfI{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solve the problem to me. I up voted. Thankss

Comment: @LeandroIP You are welcome.  You may not have enough reputation (yet) to upvote.  However, if this answer solves your problem completely and is the best (if several answers were provided), you can click the check mark to the left of the answer to "accept" it.  This tells other readers which of the several possible answers best addressed your needs.